# find the limit of this problem

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that $\int\limits_1^x e^t/t dt \sim (e^x)/x$ as $x \longrightarrow \infty$. any ideas of how to approach this problem. I can not seem to evaluate the integral either so i am real stuck in this problem

Comment: Evaluation is not possible with elementary functions this integral actually defines a function:
$$\mathrm{Ei}(x) := \int_1^x \frac{\exp(x)}x \ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Do you think it will be a good idea to find the Taylor series of this function then integrate each separately in order to find an approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By integrating by parts we get

$$\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\frac{e^t}{t}\Bigg|_1^x+\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t^2}dt$$
and using a second integration by parts we get

$$\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t^2}dt=\frac{e^t}{t^2}\Bigg|_1^x+2\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t^3}dt$$
and we have

$$\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t^3}dt\le e^x\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t^3}=\mathcal O\left(\frac{e^x}{x^2}\right)$$
hence we conclude

$$\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\frac{e^x}{x}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{e^x}{x^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 10):

The integral has no closed form. However, it's clear that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^x\frac{e^t}{t}\,dt=\infty
$$
so we can apply l'Hopital's theorem:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}
\frac{\displaystyle\int_{1}^x\frac{e^t}{t}\,dt}{e^x/x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x/x}{(xe^x-e^x)/x^2}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x-1}=1
$$

Comment: how do show that the integral goes to infinity that is actually my biggest problem in this problem.

Comment: @user146269 $e^t/t\ge1$ for $t\ge 1$